# TVILocalParticipant delegate is never called

Tags: ios, twilio

for some reason, `TVILocalParticipantDelegate` callbacks are never called in my app. Neither track-publish success nor error methods are called.

This is how I set delegate in `didConnect(to room: TVIRoom)` method.

```
public func didConnect(to room: TVIRoom) {
    guard let participant = room.localParticipant else { return }
    print("[] Did connect.")
    participant.delegate = self
}
```

However, none of this methods is called:

```
public func room(_ room: TVIRoom, didFailToConnectWithError error: Error) { ... }

public func room(_ room: TVIRoom, didDisconnectWithError error: Error?) { ... }

public func room(_ room: TVIRoom, participantDidConnect participant: TVIRemoteParticipant) { ... }

public func room(_ room: TVIRoom, participantDidDisconnect participant: TVIRemoteParticipant) { ... }
```

Note that I do get other delegate callbacks (eg. for TVIRemoteParticipants) - only TVILocalParticipant delegate is not working.
Any clue how to debug it?

Comment: the same with me